# Read a .txt file with both numerical data and words Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

i want to read .txt file in matlab with both data and words
the contents of .txt file are

```
(title "Particle Tracks")
(labels "Time" "Particle Velocity Magnitude")

((xy/key/label "particle-1")
1e-06   45.4551
2e-06   40.3895
2e-06   44.0437
3e-06   34.9606
4e-06   33.1695
4e-06   35.3499
5e-06   29.9504
6e-06   28.0226
6e-06   35.1794
7e-06   41.2255
....

((xy/key/label "particle-2")
1e-06   43.7789
1e-06   45.0513
2e-06   44.1221
3e-06   37.8328
3e-06   43.6451
4e-06   29.1166
5e-06   41.3342
6e-06   28.7241
6e-06   36.3779
7e-06   31.9631
8e-06   29.2826
9e-06   24.7755
9e-06   24.9516
1e-05   22.7528
1e-05   26.6802
1.1e-05 34.4668
```

the file extends  for 100 particles ,1st column is time and 2nd column is velocity 
 I intend to find the mean velocity of all the particles at various times of column 1,so basically i want to add corresponding column 2 values and divide them by hundred and display against the the column 1 values which is same for all the hundred particles![enter image description here][2]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read text data with a complex structure like this is to use the `fscanf` function in MATLAB.  Follow the documentation and you should be able to read the data into an array that you can used to compute the statistics you wish to find.

Another option might be to read the data in line-by-line and use regular expressions with the `regexpi` function to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input file is `input.txt`, then use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) as follows:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%n %n', 'commentStyle', '(');
a = C{1};
b = C{2};,

%# do your computations on vectors a and b

%# for example: 
ma = mean(a)
mb = mean(b)
```

You can use the vectors as you wish, e.g. you can process them 100 by 100 elements. That's up to you.